# nagios check_raid, megacli reporting wrong disk capacity, volume info on C240M5 Cisco 12G Modular Raid Controller [SAS3516]. TOSHIBA MG06SCA800A

Tags: sas, raid-controller, megacli, cisco-ucs

nagios raid_check for new CiscoC240M5 with Cisco 12G Modular Raid Controller SAS3516 was failing.

For now I've modified check_raid to skip over the volume check part, checking only the physical drives but ideally we'd want to check both, with check_raid. Has anyone found a way around this? Or should I forgo check_raid and use a wrapper script for megaclisas-status --nagios instead, accepting the (cosmetic?) problems with the virtual drive size figures?

onboard 14 disks,

- 2* 480 GB Micron_5300_MTFDDAK480TDS in RAID1
- 12* 8T TOSHIBA MG06SCA800A in RAID10 of which 2 are hot spares.

error:

```
CRITICAL: megacli:[Volumes(2): DISK0.0:,DISK1.1:; Devices(14): 00,11=Hotspare 03,09,06,12,05,01,08,10,07,04,13,02=Online]
```

Turned out to be missing data from megacli command:

```
# /usr/sbin/megacli -LdInfo -Lall -aall
Adapter 0 -- Virtual Drive Information:
Virtual Drive: 0 (Target Id: 0)

Virtual Drive: 1 (Target Id: 1)

Exit Code: 0x00
```

tip from a fellow user to use

```
# /usr/sbin/megacli ShowSummary -Aall
```

reveals another problem, the Toshiba MG06SCA800A 8T disks are reported with capacity 931.436 GB. That results in the total for the virtual drive being way off too, 4T reported instead of 36T

```
[...]
                Connector          : Port 12 - 15<Internal>: Slot 6 
                Vendor Id          : TOSHIBA 
                Product Id         : MG06SCA800A     
                State              : Online
                Disk Type          : SAS,Hard Disk Device
                Capacity           : 931.436 GB
                Power State        : Active
```

Vdisk:

```
                Virtual drive      : Target Id 1 ,VD name RAID10_12345678
                Size               : 4.547 TB
                State              : Optimal
                RAID Level         : 10
```

same for megaclisas-status since it uses megacli. disk info is right but array info is missing:

```
# megaclisas-status --nagios
RAID OK - Arrays: OK:2 Bad:0 - Disks: OK:14 Bad:0
# megaclisas-status
-- Controller information --
-- ID | H/W Model                                                        | RAM    | Temp | BBU    | Firmware     
c0    | Cisco 12G Modular Raid Controller with 2GB cache (max 16 drives) | 2048MB | 67C  | Good   | FW: 51.10.0-3612 

-- Array information --
-- ID | Type |    Size |  Strpsz | Flags | DskCache |   Status |  OS Path | CacheCade |InProgress   
c0u0  | N/A  |         |         |       |      N/A |      N/A | /dev/sda | None      |None         
c0u1  | N/A  |         |         |       |      N/A |      N/A | /dev/sdb | None      |None         

-- Disk information --
-- ID   | Type | Drive Model                                   | Size     | Status          | Speed    | Temp | Slot ID  | LSI ID  
c0u0p0  | SSD  | 202529BD123BMicron_5300_MTFDDAK480TDS D3MC000 | 446.1 Gb | Online, Spun Up | 6.0Gb/s  | 31C  | [134:13] | 13      
c0u0p1  | SSD  | 202529BCC1C0Micron_5300_MTFDDAK480TDS D3MC000 | 446.1 Gb | Online, Spun Up | 6.0Gb/s  | 32C  | [134:14] | 2       
c0u1p0  | HDD  | TOSHIBA MG06SCA800A 5701Z020A0FSFRJG          | 7.276 TB | Online, Spun Up | 12.0Gb/s | 26C  | [134:1]  | 3       
c0u1p1  | HDD  | TOSHIBA MG06SCA800A 5701Z020A05RFRJG          | 7.276 TB | Online, Spun Up | 12.0Gb/s | 26C  | [134:2]  | 9       
c0u1p0  | HDD  | TOSHIBA MG06SCA800A 5701Z020A0FRFRJG          | 7.276 TB | Online, Spun Up | 12.0Gb/s | 27C  | [134:3]  | 6       
c0u1p1  | HDD  | TOSHIBA MG06SCA800A 5701Z020A0E7FRJG          | 7.276 TB | Online, Spun Up | 12.0Gb/s | 26C  | [134:4]  | 12      
c0u1p0  | HDD  | TOSHIBA MG06SCA800A 5701Z020A05UFRJG          | 7.276 TB | Online, Spun Up | 12.0Gb/s | 26C  | [134:5]  | 5       
c0u1p1  | HDD  | TOSHIBA MG06SCA800A 5701Z020A052FRJG          | 7.276 TB | Online, Spun Up | 12.0Gb/s | 26C  | [134:6]  | 1       
c0u1p0  | HDD  | TOSHIBA MG06SCA800A 5701Z020A0EGFRJG          | 7.276 TB | Online, Spun Up | 12.0Gb/s | 26C  | [134:7]  | 8       
c0u1p1  | HDD  | TOSHIBA MG06SCA800A 5701Z020A0FEFRJG          | 7.276 TB | Online, Spun Up | 12.0Gb/s | 26C  | [134:8]  | 10      
c0u1p0  | HDD  | TOSHIBA MG06SCA800A 5701Z020A04AFRJG          | 7.276 TB | Online, Spun Up | 12.0Gb/s | 26C  | [134:9]  | 7       
c0u1p1  | HDD  | TOSHIBA MG06SCA800A 5701Z020A0KGFRJG          | 7.276 TB | Online, Spun Up | 12.0Gb/s | 26C  | [134:10] | 4       

-- Unconfigured Disk information --
-- ID   | Type | Drive Model                          | Size     | Status                | Speed    | Temp | Slot ID  | LSI ID | Path    
c0uXpY  | HDD  | TOSHIBA MG06SCA800A 5701Z020A0EFFRJG | 7.276 TB | Hotspare, Spun down   | 12.0Gb/s | 26C  | [134:11] | 0      | N/A     
c0uXpY  | HDD  | TOSHIBA MG06SCA800A 5701Z020A0DRFRJG | 7.276 TB | Hotspare, Spun down   | 12.0Gb/s | 26C  | [134:12] | 11     | N/A
```

storcli actually shows the right figures but it's not in the hwraid.le-vert.net repo's so it's offlimits